# file size exceeded the maximum size permitted phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php, phpmyadmin

I am getting following error while uploading file to phpmyadmin:

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
> the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
> configuration. See

[image]

**I am using `nginx` as web server.**

I have added following config in the nginx config file:

**in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
http {

  #default configs
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  #default configs


  #i have added following
  client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

Here is my site config file

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  
  index index.html index.php;

  server_name phpmy.xyz.com;

  root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

  # i have added following
  client_max_body_size 500M;
  
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

}
```

here is my php ini config **/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini**:

```
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 100000
memory_limit = 100M


file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_file_uploads = 20

post_max_size = 200M
```

**PHP version: 7.4.3**

can anyone know what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

PHP also has a `post_max_size` which can override `upload_max_filesize` as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size). Set this value to be slightly higher than your upload value to cover other fields in that POST request.

> post_max_size int
>
> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an int is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty. This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if $_GET['processed'] is set.

Comment: I did that but still not working

Comment: why not import from command line, there is no limit usually

Comment: @djdomi I can do that for sure. But it would make things more easier if I give access to drag and drop the databases for migrating from one server to another server

Comment: 1) PhpMyAdmin is an Admin-Panel which is in fact  IMHO out of scope for Server-Fault. 2) if you already have an SQL file mysql -u username database < file.sql is SUCH a problem for you? Please don't use Serverfault as this is for Business Users only. However, jokes beside - set `client_max_body_size 10G;` and also set the upload size for PHP to 1G - remind to restart, not only reload PHP-FPM _AND_ NGINX - because the changes sometimes need a restart not only to reload - this has irritated me in the past